# Insert DatetimePicker's value into a funtion

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, datetime-conversion

```
 private void btntest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime d = new DateTime(2016,2,13);
        LunarDate ld1 = LunarYearTools.SolarToLunar(d);
        lblamlich.Text = (ld1.ToString());
    }
```

> Note `DateTime d = new DateTime(Int year,Int month,Int day)`

How to insert datetimepicker's value into `new DateTime(2016,2,13)` ???
I tried use casting datetime to `Int` but it didn't work:

```
        string a = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
        int b = (int)(a);
        DateTime d = new DateTime(b);
        LunarDate ld1 = LunarYearTools.SolarToLunar(d);
        lblamlich.Text = (ld1.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, it should be as simple as this:

```
var d = dateTimePicker1.Value;

var newD = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day);
```

Comment: The `Value` is already a DateTime, if the goal is to get the day only (no hours) then `var dateOnly =dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;` should probably suffice

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: You are of course completely correct.  However, that was not what the questioner asked.  He specifically asked how to get the values into a new DateTime object.

Comment: Well since DateTime is a struct, assignment would "put them" into a new datetime object. My comment was mostly intended for the OP and probably should've been posted on the question

Comment: Again, you are absolutely correct.  However, the OP actually included the format that he wanted to use in the question i.e. create using new.  Correspondingly I answered in that format.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTimePicker.Value` property is already a `DateTime`. Just reference it:

```
DateTime d = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

If you're only interested in the date and wish to ignore the time, use the `DateTime.Date` property:

```
DateTime d = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```